# Apache servers in load balanced configuration have different high process watermarks

Tags: apache-2.2

We have 2 identical (as far as we can tell) apache servers in a load balanced configuration.  The servers are behind a hardware load balancer.  One of the 2 servers, during periods of relatively high load, routinely exhibits 50% higher process counts than the other server.

The obvious culprit would be a misconfiguration of the load balancer, but the amount of traffic that each server sees is nearly identical (<1% different).  The server statistics (cpu utilization) are identical or nearly identical as well.

Apache configurations (the /etc/httpd directory) are identical as well.  I suspected a longer tcp timeout on the one server but the thresholds are identical.

What other factors could be contributing?

Comment: You could start by telling us how you're doing your load balancing... (what kind of "hardware load balancer"? What mechanism does it use for distributing connections? etc.)

Comment: Its a barracuda web applicaiton firewall.  Its using stateless round robin LB.  I compared the traffic (both from apache stats and weblogs) and the traffic quantity equally balanced between severs.